# Return a value from shell script when it is called from a python script

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script `abc.sh` which is called from a Python script `custom_package.py` using `subprocess.call` function call.  I want to return a value from `abc.sh` and read it in Python.

Python call to shell script is as follows.

```
subprocess.call(['abc.sh', user, password])
```

`abc.sh` echos "running" or "not running".  How can I capture "running" or "not running" in the Python script?  Something like:

```
ret_val = subprocess.call(['abc.sh', user, password])
```

I have tried `subprocess.check_output` but it's not working.

```
ret_val = subprocess.check_output(['abc.sh', user, password])
```

Comment: Did you mistype "abc.sh" when you ran check_output()? That's what you're showing in your question.

Comment: @LukeYeager : was a type in question.fixed it in question.

Comment: there is no error ,just the return value is blank. I ran the shell script on terminal is producing output.

Comment: The code in the question is exactly how i have used check_output.

Comment: oops.sorry ..added it in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `subprocess.check_output` to capture the output of a subprocess.  If the string `'not'` is not in the returned value, the output was just `'running'`.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['abc.sh', user, password])
print(output)
running = 'not' not in output
```